# Incrementing an integer and initialisation placement having a weird effect?

Tags: c, loops, int

I have written the following 'Hangman game'-program in C (was written quick and dirty so don't mind the code too much):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word[] = "cat";
    int amountGuessesAllowed = 5;
    size_t size = sizeof(word)-1; // -1 to exclude the '\0'

    char guessedWord[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        guessedWord[i] = '_';
    }

    int lettersGuessed = 0;
    int totalTimesGuessed = 0;
    char c;

    printf("%s\n", guessedWord);
    printf("Guess %d - Enter a character: ", totalTimesGuessed+1);
    scanf("%s", &c);

    while (totalTimesGuessed < amountGuessesAllowed) {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            if (word[i] == c && guessedWord[i] == '_'){
                printf("It matches character at index %d!\n", i);
                guessedWord[i] = c;
                lettersGuessed++;
                printf("letters guessed: %d\n", lettersGuessed);
            }
        }
        totalTimesGuessed++;
        if (lettersGuessed == size) {
            printf("You win!");
            return 0;
        } else if (totalTimesGuessed == amountGuessesAllowed) {
            printf("You lose!");
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", guessedWord);
            printf("Guess %d - Enter a character: ", totalTimesGuessed+1);
            scanf("%s", &c);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue appears to be with the three initialisation lines of *lettersGuessed*, *totalTimesGuessed* and *c*.

If you execute the program and enter a couple of letters you'll notice that for some reason the `totalTimesGuessed`-value always appears to be `2`, it no longer appears to be incrementing. There don't appear to be any problems with the `lettersGuessed`-variable.

```
___
Guess 1 - Enter a character: b
___
Guess 2 - Enter a character: c
It matches character at index 0!
letters guessed: 1
c__
Guess 2 - Enter a character: j
c__
Guess 2 - Enter a character:
```

Now if you were to swap the order of the `lettersGuessed` and `totalTimesGuessed` then the `lettersGuessed`-variable is having the issue (remains 1)!

```
___
Guess 1 - Enter a character: c
It matches character at index 0!
letters guessed: 1
c__
Guess 2 - Enter a character: a
It matches character at index 1!
letters guessed: 1
ca_
Guess 3 - Enter a character:
```

Finally, if I were to place the `char c;` line before the two ints:

```c
char c;
int lettersGuessed = 0;
int totalTimesGuessed = 0;
```

Then everything works as expected!

```
___
Guess 1 - Enter a character: c
It matches character at index 0!
letters guessed: 1
c__
Guess 2 - Enter a character: a
It matches character at index 1!
letters guessed: 2
ca_
Guess 3 - Enter a character:
```

I've tested this in Xcode with gcc.

There must be a logical explanation for this? I hunger for enlightenment!

Comment: `guessedWord` isn't NUL-terminated, so `printf("%s\n", guessedWord);` causes Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are causing undefined behavior in

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

because `"%s"` specifier adds a terminating `nul` byte to the target which is a single `char`.

Instead you can try

```
if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1)
    handleErrorPlease();
```

the space before the `"%c"` is intentional, it will eat any white space character left by any previous call to `scanf`.

When undefined behavior occurs, it's up to the layout of the program in when it's loaded memory what would actually happen, hence changing the order of the defined variables causes the behavior to be different.

Comment: It works with your modification! But any idea why it also works if I place the 'char c;' above the two ints and leave the scanf-line untouched?

Comment: Care to explain why changing the order of the defined variables makes to code work correctly?

Comment: @YannickDeTurck  and Beele, Undefined Behavior means anything can happen. It might work the first time, but might fail on adding a `printf` or doing something else.